# run npm install fail with message "Not Found: electron-to-chromium......"

Tags: ionic3, npm-install

I create an ionic3 project,select tabs.When run npm install ,I got an error message:
"404 Not Found: electron-to-chromium@https://registry.npm.taobao.org/electron-to-chromium/download/electron-to-chromium-1.3.137.tgz",and the project can't run with "ionic serve" either,I don't know why... ...

Answer (score 0):

Add below code under dependencies in package.json and then run npm install.

```
"electron-to-chromium": "^1.3.137"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try reseting electrone**

```
npm uninstall -g electron-forge
npm i -g electron-forge
electron-forge init test
cd test
electron-forge start
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete my package-lock.json then run 'npm install' again. That updated the node_modules/electron-to-chromium version in package-lock.json to a version it can install.